# Delphi Mocks with class helper

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, mocking, delphi-mocks

I really like Delphi Mocks, but it seems to have a problem with class helpers. I have a class helper that extends TRESTResponse and want to test the functions I added. Unfortunately, this does not work. I have created the following simple reproduction:

```
MyClass = class
  function MyFunc1: Integer; virtual;
end;

MyClassHelper = class helper for MyClass
  function MyFunc2: Integer; virtual;
end;

var
  LMock: TMock<MyClass>;
begin
  LMock := TMock<MyClass>.Create;
  LMock.Setup.WillReturn(2).When.MyFunc1;
  LMock.Setup.WillReturn(2).When.MyFunc2;
  Assert(LMock.Instance.MyFunc1 <> 1);
  Assert(LMock.Instance.MyFunc2 <> 1);
end;

function MyClass.MyFunc1: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;

function MyClassHelper.MyFunc2: Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;
```

Mocking MyFunc1 works as expected, but MyFunc2 cannot be mocked. The second LMock.Setup.WillReturn-line raises an exception `[MyClass] already defines Will Return When for method [MyFunc1]`. If you remove the mocking setup for `MyFunc1` then no exception is raised, but `MyFunc2` is not mocked.

Any suggestions how to solve this? Or is it not possible to mock class helpers with Delphi Mocks?